# badarg when trying to read a csv file in erlang, with tsung

Tags: parsing, csv, erlang, load-testing, tsung

I am using [tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/) to load test my websocket server. I am new to `tsung` and to `erlang`.

I have a list of users and keys exported to a .csv file. To get it running i reduced the csv file to:

```
1;2
```

with no empty line at the end of the file.

This is a snippet of my `tsung` config (otherwise working fine):

```
 <options>
    <option name="file_server" id="users" value="PATH_TO_MY_CSV/users.csv"/>
  </options>
   [...]

    <setdynvars sourcetype="erlang" callback="loadusers:user">
      <var name="connection_url" />
    </setdynvars>

   [...]
    <request subst="true">             
         <websocket type="connect" path="/?%%_connection_url%%"/>
    </request>
```

Here's my `loadusers.erl`, which makes use of [a ts_file_server tsung module](https://github.com/processone/tsung/blob/master/src/tsung_controller/ts_file_server.erl):

```
-module(loadusers).
-export([user/1]).

user({Pid,DynVar})->
   {ok,Line} = ts_file_server:get_next_line(),
   [Username, Passwd] = string:tokens(Line,";"),
   "username=" ++ Username ++"&password=" ++ Passwd.
```

Here's the erlang error stack:

```
** State machine <0.90.0> terminating 
** Last message in was {timeout,#Ref<0.0.0.414>,end_thinktime}
** When State == think
**      Data  == {state_rcv,none,
                     {{0,0,0,0},0},
                     undefined,0,10000,"192.168.59.103",443,ts_tcp,
                     {proto_opts,negociate,"/http-bind/","/chat","binary",10,
                         600000,infinity,32768,32768,undefined,undefined,[]},
                     true,1,undefined,true,undefined,
                     {1431,872144,388666},
                     6,6,false,undefined,0,[],<<>>,
                     {websocket_session,undefined,undefined},
                     0,2,524288,524288,
                     [{tsung_userid,2}],
                     ts_websocket,[],undefined,none}
** Reason for termination = 
** {{badarg,[{dict,fetch,
                   [default,
                    {dict,1,16,16,8,80,48,
                          {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]},
                          {{[],[],[],
                            [[users|{file,{<<"1;2">>},1,-1}]],
                            [],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]}}}],
                   [{file,"dict.erl"},{line,130}]},
             {ts_file_server,handle_call,3,
                             [{file,"src/tsung_controller/ts_file_server.erl"},
                              {line,159}]},
             {gen_server,try_handle_call,4,
                         [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,607}]},
             {gen_server,handle_msg,5,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,639}]},
             {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,237}]}]},
    {gen_server,call,[{global,ts_file_server},{get_next_line,default}]}}
```

I know `dynvars` can be directly pulled from a tsung [config](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/user_manual/conf-advanced-features.html), but I need to do it in the script since later I will need to dynamically manipulate the data. **IMPORTANT**: reading the same csv file works fine, so it seems like the script is the problem.

**Can someone explain to me what erlang is complaining about here?**

Answer (score 0):

The error message is saying that `dict:fetch(default, SomeDict)` was called and threw a `badarg` exception. Typically this would happen when the key (`default` in your case) doesn't exist.

The problem is that in the Tsung config you set `id="users"`, which sets the file id to `users`. But `ts_file_server:get_next_line/0` expects the file id to be `default`.

Either remove `id="users"` from the config or change the Erlang part to use `ts_file_server:get_next_line/1`, passing in the file id you used in the config file.